# MinIO docker SSL login connection refused

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, minio, connection-refused

We are using docker compose to setup MinIO service, now we are adding the SSL security.

Login screen displays without problem on `https://my.domain:9001` but it fails on login attempt.

When env variable `MINIO_SERVER_URL` is left out, the error says `Post "https://SOME_IP_ADDRESS:9000/": x509: cannot validate certificate for SOME_IP_ADDRESS because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`.

When `MINIO_SERVER_URL=https://my.domain:9000` or `MINIO_SERVER_URL=https://my.domain:9001` the error becomes `Post "https://my.domain:9000/": dial tcp SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:9000: connect: connection refused`.

Before implementing SSL it worked on SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:9001 which becomes unavailable after setting cert volumes in docker-compose.yml

From browser network dev tools the response number is 500 with message "invalid login" regardless credentials being correct or not.

MinIO buckets are accessible from other services.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - MINIO_SERVER_URL=https://my.domain:9000
    volumes:
      - ./data_docker/raw:/data
      - ${PATH_CERT_FILE}:/root/.minio/certs/public.crt:ro
      - ${PATH_CERT_PRIVATE_KEY}:/root/.minio/certs/private.key:ro
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "https://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
    restart: always
```

Any tips how to solve this error?

Comment: Have you tried leaving the port off the URL variable?  The documentation specifically mentions this issue, you should read it.  https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/minio/

Comment: Leaving it out means defaulting to port 80 or 443 which operates other (different) service. But I will try it out of pure helplessness.

Comment: Can you give some more information about networking, proxies, or load balancing that's going on?  What does "my.domain" resolve as?  It seems like perhaps port `9000` is not being forwarded properly if the connection is being refused.  Presumably the SSL cert is for "my.domain" which explains why accessing it by the IP address is not trusted.

Comment: Finaly got some time for this issue. "my.domain" resolves to SERVER_IP_ADDRESS there is nothing more to that (or if you want default port 80 and 443...), port 9000 and 9001 without SSL works,  loadbalancing - no idea, cert is indeed for "my.domain" yet this same approach works for other (not minio) services running under 9002, 9003 and 9004

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet is to set hosts since minio itself doesn't know about "my.domain" which is required to access minio over ssl.

This can be done with adding following to docker-compose

```
  minio:
    ...
    extra_hosts:
      - "my.domain:127.0.0.1"
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I did not try `extra_hosts` but solved it already and forgot I wrote a question here that I can post the solution to.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding `hostname:`  to specify domain

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
# Specify the URL hostname the MinIO Console should use for connecting to the MinIO Server.
      - MINIO_SERVER_URL=https://my.domain:9000
# The hostname a container uses for itself. Defaults to the container’s ID if not specified.
    hostname: my.domain
    volumes:
      - ./data_docker/raw:/data
# https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69320949/5990202
      - ${PATH_CERT_FILE}:/root/.minio/certs/public.crt:ro
      - ${PATH_CERT_PRIVATE_KEY}:/root/.minio/certs/private.key:ro
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "https://my.domain:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
    restart: always
```